# What are the step to move all your dotfiles into XDG directories?

Tags: xdg

The [XDG Base Directory Specification](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) provide a set of directory one may used to store data that used to go in so called dot files/directory in the user folder. This post aims to help users who desire use this directories as much as possible.

Answer (score 26):

Indeed, the current short answer to the question is *you can't*, as some application hardcode the path. Nevertheless, many application which doesn't specifically support XDG directories enable to set other directories through environment variables. Some time you need to be able to change the system wide configuration, for example with shell, but most of the time, you should be able perform the step as a unprivileged user.

## Setting your shell

```bash
# Setting bash to use $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/bash, defaults to ~/.config/bash
confdir=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/bash

### Moving existing files
mkdir -p -- "$confdir"
for file in "$HOME"/.bash*; do
    dest=$confdir/$(basename "${file:1}") 
    mv -i -- "$file" "$dest" # don't overwrite without permission
done

### Sourcing and setting variables
sudo sh -c 'cat >>/etc/profile.d/bash_in_xdg_config_home.sh <<CONF
# Make bash follow the XDG_CONFIG_HOME convention
_confdir=\${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-\$HOME/.config}/bash
if [ -d "$_confdir" ] &&  [ "\$0" = "bash" ]
then
    . "\$_confdir"/bash_profile
    . "\$_confdir"/bashrc
    HISTFILE=\$_confdir/bash_history
fi
unset _confdir
CONF
'

sudo sh -c 'cat >>/etc/bash.bash_logout <<CONF
if [ -s "\${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-\$HOME/.config}/bash/bash_logout" ]
then
    . "\${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-\$HOME/.config}/bash/bash_logout"
fi
CONF
'

# Setting zsh
## System wide configuration (using xdg directories)
sudo sh -c 'cat >>/etc/zshenv <<CONF
if [[ -d "\${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-\$HOME/.config}"/zsh ]]
then
        export ZDOTDIR=\${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-\$HOME/.config}/zsh
fi
CONF
'
```

If you use several shell, for example zsh for interactive shell, but an other for scripting, you may want to `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/profile` file, that you will source in relevant shell initialization script.

## Setting environment variables

```bash
# bazaar
export BZRPATH=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/bazaar
export BZR_PLUGIN_PATH=$XDG_DATA_HOME/bazaar
export BZR_HOME=$XDG_CACHE_HOME/bazaar

# gnupg
export GNUPGHOME=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/gnupg

# ICEauthority
export ICEAUTHORITY=${XDG_CACHE_HOME}/ICEauthority

#  less
export LESSHISTFILE="${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/less/history"
export LESSKEY="${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/less/keys"



# mplayer
export MPLAYER_HOME=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/mplayer

# subversion
export SUBVERSION_HOME=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/subversion


# vim
export VIMINIT='let $MYVIMRC="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim/vimrc" | source $MYVIMRC'
export VIMDOTDIR="$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/vim"
```

## Work around

### SSH

SSH does provide a way to change the client configuration file, but – as far as I found – only through command line. So one solution to always invoke the clients with a none default emplacement may be :

```bash
if [ -s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/ssh/config" ]
then
    SSH_CONFIG="-F ${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/ssh/config"
fi
if [ -s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/ssh/id_dsa" ]
then
    SSH_ID="-i ${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/ssh/id_dsa"
fi

alias ssh="ssh $SSH_CONFIG $SSH_ID "
alias ssh-copy-id="ssh-copy-id $SSH_ID"
```

And your `${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/ssh/config` should contain something like :

```bash
Host *
    IdentityFile /home/user/.config/ssh/id_dsa
    UserKnownHostsFile /home/user/.config/ssh/known_hosts
```

## What doesn't work yet

Although `GNUPGHOME` is a documented variable, under Fedora 21 you'll end up with the creation of a new `~/.gnupg` directory when you launch a new session.

Although `ICEauthority` is a documented variable, under Fedora 21 you'll end up with the creation of a new cookie when you launch a new session.

The dotfile `~/.swt` content should probably be stored directly into `${XDG_DATA_HOME}`, as both have `lib` directories. No documentation was found on how to to that if it's possible.

**Mozilla** products doesn't support an appropriate environment variable, see [Mozilla products doesn't allow to use a custom user configuration directory](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1128692) and [Support for the Freedesktop.org XDG Base Directory Specification](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=259356).

## Other useful sources

- [Move your config files to $XDG_CONFIG_HOME](http://lxl.io/xdg-config-home)
- https://github.com/woegjiub/.config/blob/master/bash/xdg.sh
- http://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/2v8rv2/move_your_config_files_to_xdg_config_home/ (Move your config files to `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME`)
- https://github.com/grawity/dotfiles/blob/master/.dotfiles.notes

Comment: When using bash as interactive non-login shell (normal terminal usage), shouldn't /etc/profile be not read at all? Won't our definitions be not set then?

Comment: According to the manpage on my system, you are right. Now what I would suggest you is to simply test, as it may depends on your system default configuration. Please give feed back, thank you.

Comment: I can confirm that /etc/profile is not read for non-login shells. But, if you open tmux your /etc/profile is read. This is because tmux opens all its shells as login shells.

Comment: things like history files should be stored under `$XDG_CACHE_HOME`

Comment: 1) Add: `export XAUTHORITY="$XDG_CACHE_HOME/Xauthority"` 2) Please quote your variables! (see (1) for an example)
3) For my `bash`, I needed to: `export XDG_CONFIG_HOME=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:="$HOME/.config"}`

Answer (score 11):

I recommend consulting the Arch Linux wiki page [XDG Base Directory support](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_Base_Directory_support) which is continuously updated.

**GIT**

I just moved my `.gitconfig` to `XDG_CONFIG_HOME` on OSX. Per the git-config documentation (link omitted due to reputation).

```
Second user-specific configuration file. If $XDG_CONFIG_HOME is not set or
empty, $HOME/.config/git/config will be used. Any single-valued variable 
set in this file will be overwritten by whatever is in ~/.gitconfig. It is
a good idea not to create this file if you sometimes use older versions of
Git, as support for this file was added fairly recently.
```

I set the environment variable using the instructions in [Setting the system-wide PATH environment variable in Mavericks](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/106814/100629). Note that you will need to create the file `XDG_CONFIG_HOME/git/config` yourself and if `~/.gitconfig` exists it will take precedence.

**VIM**

I used Tom Vincent's 2011 article [Vim respect XDG](https://tlvince.com/vim-respect-xdg) and it seems to work. I'm not sure about the above answer; `VIMDOTDIR` doesn't seem to be a thing.

Comment: Note: I'm moving to using https://nixos.org/ which makes it possible to completely control all configuration in an elegant manner

Comment: sourcing vimrc from `zsh` gives a permission error

Answer (score 5):

Zsh does a slightly better job than bash letting you de-clutter your home using the `$ZDOTDIR` variable. To move zsh out of the way, you need to add the following to your `~/.zshenv` file:

```
# ~/.zshenv contents
# this is the bare bones setup to move everything to XDG dir
ZDOTDIR=$HOME/.config/zsh
```

If you have root privledges, you could add this instead to `/etc/zsh/zshenv` and avoid the need for any zsh dotfiles in your $HOME. From here, all your other zsh dotfiles can be moved to `~/.config/zsh`, like `.zshrc`. I also recommend adding your zsh history to the `$XDG_DATA_HOME` location: `HISTFILE=$XDG_DATA_HOME/zsh/zsh_history`.

Some apps will look for the XDG locations by default and you may not even realize it because you still have a legacy dotfile in your $HOME directory. Git is a good example of this - if you have a `~/.gitconfig`, try moving it to `~/.config/git/config`. My personal favorite, [Fish Shell](http://fishshell.com/), uses ~/.config by default too.

Also, check your other apps for their own version of a re-$HOME-ing variable. Many support it XDG via a variable:

- Atom: `export ATOM_HOME=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/atom`
- lpass: `export LPASS_HOME=$XDG_CONFIG_HOME/lpass`
- rupa/z has one: `export _Z_DATA=$XDG_DATA_HOME/z/z.txt`

But there's still quite an extensive XDG wall of shame. [Tmux has been actively hostile](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/issues/142) to supporting de-cluttering your $HOME. [Same with pylint](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/issues/1364). [And Julia](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4630). And the list goes on. [Arch keeps a nice running list of XDG support here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_Base_Directory).

Honestly, I can't understand the resistance to supporting it. Users need to clearly send a clear message that apps shouldn't be running roughshod over their $HOME. It's not okay anymore. A modern system uses hundreds of apps that pollute $HOME, not tens like it used to be 20 years ago.

Answer (score 3):

The most complete resource I’ve found for cleaning up my home directory is [xdg-ninja](https://github.com/b3nj5m1n/xdg-ninja). It’s a tool that inspects the dotfiles and -directories in your home directory and prints a list of solutions for how to configure each individual of software that clutters the home directory. It doesn’t know every single software, of course (and there’s *no solution* for some!<sup>1</sup>) but it’s by far the most complete individual list out there, and the tool accepts pull requests for as-yet missing tools.

---

<sup>1</sup> Short of [an unmaintained hack via `LD_PRELOAD`](http://ordiluc.net/fs/libetc/).