# OpenSSH modify location of user's specific files to comply with XDG specification

Tags: ssh, openssh, xdg

Is it possible to modify the default location of the user's specific files of OpenSSH (`~/.ssh`)?

I've found the [XDG base directory specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html) and I was wondering if it was possible to make OpenSSH compliant with it?

Comment: Related: [What are the steps to move all your dotfiles into XDG directories?](https://superuser.com/q/874901/23156)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible.

This was evoked in
[Bug 2050: Support XDG basedir specification](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2050),
whose status is "CLOSED WONTFIX".
Following demands by users were no longer answered after the following
final answer from 2012:

> OpenSSH (and it's ancestor ssh-1.x) have a 17 year history of using
> ~/.ssh. This location is baked into innumerable users' brains,
> millions of happily working configurations and countless tools.
>
> Changing the location of our configuration would require a very strong
> justification and following a trend of desktop applications (of which
> OpenSSH is not) is not sufficient.

Arch Linux adds one more reason for this in its status report
[XDG Base Directory](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/XDG_Base_Directory):

> Assumed to be present by many ssh daemons and clients such as DropBear and OpenSSH.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you *could*, as OpenSSH gives you a few options to specify alternate paths for some (and possibly all) of the usual files in `~/.ssh`.

But be aware that this is *very* unconventional, will have a different approach for each file, and might require superuser privileges to change settings for both ssh client and the server. It certainly won't be *convenient*, and it may have a number of corner cases where it fails.

That said, let's try this as a fun exercise:

- Assuming `export SSH_HOME=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/ssh`
- `~/.ssh/config`: can be changed via command line `ssh -F "$SSH_HOME"/config`
- `~/.ssh/id_{ed25519,rsa}{,.pub}`: also command line `ssh -i "$SSH_HOME"/id_ed25519` (or `-o IdentityFile="$SSH_HOME"/id_ed25519`). Can be specified multiple times to try different keys.
- `~/.ssh/known_hosts`: `ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile="$SSH_HOME"/known_hosts`
- `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`: this requires aid from `sshd` (the server), drop a `xxx.conf`  file in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/xxx.conf` containing `AuthorizedKeysFile ~/.config/ssh/authorized_keys`, either as a global statement or in a per-user `Match user xxx` block. In any case you'd have to hard-code `~/.config/ssh` as it can't expand `XDG_CONFIG_HOME`.

For `UserKnownHostsFile` and `IdentityFile`, you could also alternatively set them in your `"$SSH_HOME"/config`, or drop a config override file in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/xxx.conf` containing the option(s), but the same restriction on hard-coding `~/.config/ssh` applies.

Summing it up:

```bash
sudo tee /etc/ssh/sshd_config.d/00-xdg.conf <<< 'AuthorizedKeysFile ~/.config/ssh/authorized_keys'
export SSH_HOME=${XDG_CONFIG_HOME:-$HOME/.config}/ssh
alias ssh='ssh -F "$SSH_HOME"/config -i "$SSH_HOME"/id_ed25519 -o UserKnownHostsFile="$SSH_HOME"/known_hosts'
```

Not for the faint of heart... and not recommended either.

But hey, it *can* be done! ;-)

Comment: Maybe this worthless pedantry, but can you make a `~/.config/ssh` folder and symlink `~/.ssh` to it? Then everyone's happy, no?

Comment: @Michael, you could, but this would completely defeat the OP's purpose of _moving_ the SSH dir out of `~/.ssh`. If you're going keep it there, even as a symlink, it's best to simply leave it alone and not have all this trouble.